# Kernel panic while installing Centos 6.5 from USB stick and USB cd rom

Tags: linux, boot, usb, centos

I tried to install CentosOS 6.5 using CentOS-6.5-x86_64-LiveCD as a source. I made bootable USB using YUMI (later LinuxLive USB creator) and booted but got the following error:

```
i915 0000:00:02.0: More than 8 outputs detected

Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Tainted: G --------------- H 2.6.32-431.e16.x86_64 #1
Call trace:
    [<ffffffff815271fa>] ? panic+0xa7/0x16f
    [<ffffffff81077622>] ? do_exit+0x862/0x870
    [<ffffffff8118a865>] ? fput+0x25/0x30
    [<ffffffff81077688>] ? do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
    [<ffffffff81077717>] ? sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
    [<ffffffff8100b072>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
drm_kms_helper: panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

Same error comes either with trying to install from USB stick and USB cd rom.
Same error comes, if I choose verify & boot and install text mode.

**My question is, what could be the problem and could a normal sata cd rom help?**

### EDIT1

Tried Debian and it booted fine. Friend suggested not to use Live version of centos but the full 4+ gb dvd. Going to try it soon and post the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso instead of the live one and everything worked as expected.